# How to unprotect/see the code of a command in Mathematica

Tags: command-line, code

How do you see the code form of a command in Mathematica?

I know there is a command in Mathematica, "Unprotect[]", but how do you actually use this?

Comment: Do notice many of the built-in functions are just blackboxes, but definitions of functions that are not blackboxes can be checked with the tools above, particularly the `PrintDefinitions`.

Answer (score 3):

`Unprotect[]` is there to remove the `Protected` attribute. This allows the definition of a command to be modified, but doesn't necessarily allow you to see the code that makes up the unmodified command. `Protect` helps to prevent accidental changes like `+=3` redefining the `+` command. You can even `Protect` your own functions if you're worried about accidentally changing a definition.

If you want to read the Wolfram code, I have used:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Charting`ScaledTicks]
```

to access some of the definitions. However, Mathematica is proprietary software. There are many functions where this won't work. For example, `PrintDefinitions[NDSolve]` shows a few options, but the actual code itself is a kernel function that cannot be read in this way. If you really want to read the code itself for **any** arbitrary function, I suspect the only way is to apply for a position at WRI.